# What does include() in urls.py do in django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to django. I came across the `include()` method. I read the documentation regarding it. But couldn't understand it as it lacked suitable examples. I am again rewriting this question in a proper way so that it doesn't sound baseless. Can someone please help me out by giving me a suitable example regarding the scenario in which the `include()` method becomes handy?

Comment: Although you're new to Django, you obviously haven't/aren't reading the Django documentation. Find what you looking for here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: You've answered your own question, it includes another urls file. Why are you asking?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if you don't want to answer, then don't answer, I am asking about how remapping is done ?

Comment: There isn't any remapping, why do you think there is?

Comment: Then, what will happen in the eg. I have given in the question ?

Comment: @Rexford, django docs is very big and I am not able to understand, from where to start. Whatever topic I read, I am finding the references of other topics, which are not known to me. So, I think, It's better to ask it over here. But knowledgeable users like you, instead of answering, downvotes the question.

Comment: @user2393267 I understand you wish to get up and running quickly with your Django studies, but trust me, there're no shortcuts. Read the docs. Almost all the questions (including the `include`) are in there.

Comment: `include` can include things other that another urls file, correct? It could be used to include an html file in another template, can't it?

OP's question is a good one and these RTFM answers are too dismissive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`include()` adds urls from your app directory's `urls.py` to the main urls.py (in memory).  This keeps the main urls.py from getting too big to read.

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/

The Including Other URLConfs section.

Answer (score -2):

```
path (**'home/'**, include ('yourapp_dir.urls'))
```

Include loads the URL patterns from the `url.py` file which is in `name_app dir`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('page', views.page1, name='page1')
]

localhost:8000/home/**page** is **ok** 

localhost:8000/**page** Page not found
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).