# Why cant I add a new page to my Django project?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add another page to my Django project. At first the problem was that the tutorial I was using was asking to use url so i switched it to re_path but it is still not working and giving me many errors. Right now my urls.py looks like this:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from myapp import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^hello/$', include (views.hello)),
]
```

However I keep getting an error that says "File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 725, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<function hello at 0x000001C657C0F2E0>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see the 'urlpatterns' variable with
valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

Amonge other errors for files I have not edited yet.

Comment: The purpose of `include` is to include the entire contents of another `urls.py` file.  But it looks like you're trying to add just one view.  Why are you using `include` for that?  Just use `views.hello` directly.  You don't need `include()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does include() in urls.py do in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532804/what-does-include-in-urls-py-do-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `path` and `re_path` lay in the nature of the url string you pass it (`re_path` expects a regex) but otherwise the args are the same.

You can either pass a single route, or use `include()` to include all the routes from another module (but `admin.site.urls` is an exception, as stated in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/))

You probably want:

```
django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', views.hello),
]
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/) also.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `include()`: is to include all urls which are defined in other `app.urls` file. and syntax is `include('app.urls')`

for your case you are not including other 'app.urls' file,
you are just handling one specific route by your 'hello' view
So that is why you should use your **views.hello** view directly because that will be responsible for handling that hello/ route